# How would you write a regular expression that parse the style tags and a variable number of spans

Tags: php, html, regex

I need to write a regular expression that parses style tags (top and left positions as well as span id) and a variable number of spans.  I'm using pcre (php). My sample text is comprised of text with 1, 2 and 3 spans and follows:

```
<div class="txt" style="position:absolute; left:141px; top:159px;"><span id="f4" style="font-size:11px;vertical-align:baseline;color:#e5e5e5;">Sam</span></div>

<div class="txt" style="position:absolute; left:170px; top:170px;"><span id="f46" style="font-size:10px;vertical-align:baseline;color:#000000;">Sam</span><span id="f43" style="font-size:2px;vertical-align:baseline;color:#000000;">Bill</span></div>

<div class="txt" style="position:absolute; left:170px; top:170px;"><span id="f46" style="font-size:10px;vertical-align:baseline;color:#000000;">Bill</span><span id="f43" style="font-size:2px;vertical-align:baseline;color:#000000;">Jane</span><span id="f46" style="font-size:10px;vertical-align:baseline;color:#000000;">Jim</span></div>
```

I would like the output to look like:

Text 1:
1: 141
2: 159
3: f4
4: Sam

Text 2:
1: 170
2: 170
3: f46
4: Sam
5: f43
6: Bill

Text 3:
1: 170
2: 170
3: f46
4: Sam
5: f43
6: Bill
7: f46
8: Jim

I have a sandbox at Regex101: [Regex Sandbox](https://regex101.com/r/7at2Iz/4)

When writing an expression like this can one use a single span section that can be repeated one or more times or do I have to have a one-for-one match for each span?

Comment: @chris85 I had the wrong link. I have made some progress with the regular expression, but I'm still no expert.

Comment: That's a better sandbox :). You still should use a parser to enter the style attributes of the elements you want to target.

Comment: @chris85 Unfortunately another parser is not an option.  I do think I will have fairly clean HTML to work with

Comment: Maybe split each div then use https://regex101.com/r/7at2Iz/5?